# PHP Compare a comma seperated string with keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to compare a comma separated string to an arrays keys like I have below, so If they match, I can mark those check boxes as checked.

I'm stuck on this. How can this be done? I can compare two arrays, but I can't think of a way to compare a comma separated string and the keys of an array. Can you help please?

```
$countries = array (
    "US" => "United States Of America",
    "GB" => "United Kingdom",
    "CA" => "Canada",
    "SE" => "Sweden",
    "AU" => "Australia",
);

$str = 'US,CA,SE'; // This comes from a MySql table

foreach ($countries as $code=>$name) {

    if(//value in comma seperated string == array key i.e US == US) {
        echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="'.$code.'" checked>'.$name.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="'.$code.'">'.$name.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$selected_countries = array_flip(explode(',', $str));

foreach ($countries as $code => $name) {
    echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="'.$code.'" ' . 
        (isset($selected_countries[$code]) ? 'checked' : '') .
        '>'.$name.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: There are several errors here. Even when I corrected them, this did not work. `Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\web\apache\htdocs\test\checkBoxes.php on line 13 Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\web\apache\htdocs\test\checkBoxes.php on line 13 `

Comment: Sorry, left out the delimiter argument to `explode`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$countries = array (
    "US" => "United States Of America",
    "GB" => "United Kingdom",
    "CA" => "Canada",
    "SE" => "Sweden",
    "AU" => "Australia",
);

$str = 'US,CA,SE';
$selected_countries = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($countries as $code=>$name) {

    if(in_array($code, $selected_countries)) {
        echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="'.$code.'" checked>'.$name.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="'.$code.'">'.$name.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Here I use `explode()` to put the three countries in an array. I then find those that match the keys we have in `$countries` using `array_keys()` to get those keys and `array_intersect()` to find the matches. I then compare the keys in `$countries` against each one we had in our string using `in_array()`.

Comment: Doing the intersection seems unnecessary? The `in_array` test on `$selected_countries` will do the same thing

Comment: @EmilyShepherd I can see you're correct. Can I leave it out?

Comment: @EmilyShepherd Or, maybe he's put it there for a good reason.

Comment: @Norman, I don't want to speak for @JohnConde, but yeah if you miss out `$matches = ...` and then use `in_array($code, $selected_contries)` I believe that will work the same :) x